# 'No Such Interface Supported' error when trying to connect to a remote PC in the Performance Monitor

Tags: windows-7, remote-access, performance-monitor

I'm trying to get the remote performance monitoring running. I do following.

1. Start up 'Performance Monitor'
2. Right click on 'Performance on the top and select 'Connect to another computer'
3. There I choose my remote machine.

I've also done following things:

1. Added the 'Performance Logs and Alerts' to the firewall exception
2. Started the 'Remote Registry Service' (without it I get the 'path not found error'
3. Start the 'Performance Logs and Alerts' service.

I'm running Windows 7 Professional on both machines.

Update: I'm not sure if I really have Admin rights when I login remotely. Is there a way to explicitly specify the user which is used on the remote machine?

Comment: It's a lot easier if you are in a domain. If you're not in a domain and it's windows XP or newer, you have to deal with a bunch of firewall, DCOM permissions, and user rights.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a similar question over on StackOverflow you may want to check out: [Issues remoting to perfmon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5399603/issues-remoting-to-perfmon).

Apparently the user fixed it by [resetting the target machine's registry permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5399603/issues-remoting-to-perfmon/5399840#5399840).

Also, ensure your user account has administrator rights on both systems, and/or is a member of the "Performance Monitor Users" group on the target machine.  See [here for more info](http://sourcedaddy.com/windows-7/performance-monitor-user-rights.html) on Performance Monitor user rights.

Comment: Thanks for the links. Unfortunately nothing of this fixed my issue =(

Comment: @Gamlor see my answer!

Answer (score 0):

The reason why perfmon.exe do not want to connect to the remote server is, it wants to connect to the Perf Monitor **and** the Perf Logs (Data collections).

So you have to add the user account to **also the Log User group** and of course to the Monitor Users.

[image]

you don't need to be local admin on the remote server!